# "I didn't have any work experience before" vs. "I don't have any work experience before"

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense

> But for me, as long as I can enhance my skills, I won't care much about my job since I **didn't** have any work experience before.

edit: Sorry for the confusion, I will edit to make it more concise and clear.

In this context, there is no work experience at all, but the model of this sentence is to describe that with having no work experience, that I won't mind to take any job so long as it can enhance my skills.

I am not sure which tense case to use for *don't* vs *didn't* to describe that I have no work experience.

Comment: I don't understand what the model sentence means. Does it mean that you didn't have work experience before some unstated event, but now you do have work experience? In that case, since you now DO have work experience, it would be strange to say that you DO NOT have work experience.

Comment: Yeah the model sentence is kind of confusing. But in this context, there's no work experience at all

Comment: Well of course the word choice should be guided by the message that you are trying to verbalize. If you mean you are now happy to take any work that enhances your skills because you don't have work experience, then you should say that -- "don't." (Perhaps you're tempted to use the past tense because you're thinking of saying something different -- that you "didn't" yet work in the field. You "don't" have experience, but you "didn't" work.)

Comment: @Cascabel I have edited and revised the question. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're describing your current experience, then you should use the present tense "don't".

If you're talking about your experience in the past, but it has changed since then, you should use the past tense "didn't".

In your case, the first seems to apply, so you should use "don't".

Also, the word "before" doesn't really fit in. Before what? "yet" or "so far" would be better.

> As long as I can enhance my skills, I won't care much about my job since I don't have any experience yet.